# Realtime vector engine

Tags: cartography

Hey guys, I am looking for a real-time GIS vector engine that is to be used on a device using Embedded Linux/Qt (commercial or opensource). 
Any suggestions? Thanks.

The usecase is a non-certified navigation system for airplanes, the data comes from a spatialite database. The data itself is not dynamic. Currently we are using rastercharts only, but we'd like to add the option of aviation vector charts, drawn on top of a raster layer.

Comment: What do you mean "real-time" in this case? Is your data going to change in real-time, or are you just looking for a good screen refresh rate? Embedded Linux/Qt has QGraphicsLineItem and QGraphicsSvgItem for instance, which are designed for fast rendering. If you want real-time data update, does your GIS data come from internal storage or over a network from a remote server?

Comment: What are you going to do with this "real-time GIS vector engine"?

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I couldn't add a comment, that's why I edited the question.